# Поиск слэша в строке в PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Недавно понадобилось найти в строке слэши. Решил использовать такой код:

```
$ret = substr_count($uploadfilename,'\\');
```

$uploadfilename содержит код символов типа "\u0414\u4414".

Код не срабатывает выдает 0, странно как-то, хотя такое ощущение, что ошибка на уровне не поставленной запятой.

Comment: необходимо найти их количество или вообще присутствие?

Comment: Скопировал код, проверил - результат: 2

Comment: Количество. А почему тогда может не работать?

Comment: Может слэши в разные стороны?

Comment: @tabby_cat да нет, вроде пробовал все равно не помогает к тому же у Barton'a этот код работат. Ощущение что что-то на сервере с настройками.

Comment: Какой сервер, ОС? Я на ubuntu сейчас,apache, php 5.3.10

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что у Вас строка юникод и Вы смотрите на ее абстрактное представление в виде последовательностей  `\uxxxx` и думаете, что это именно тот текст в котором надо считать слэши, а на самом деле у Вас не  

    \u0414\u4414
в строке, а  

    Д[иероглиф]

Comment: @Barton 

Система такая:
Linux 2.6.18-308.8.2.el5.028stab101.1 #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 20:25:35 MSD 2012 x86_64 
PHP Version 5.2.17

Может какие-нибудь нужно настройки в ядре поправить...

Comment: Ага, давайте допилим ядро.  
Приведите код как Вы получаете UpLoadFilename и как Вы определяете содержимое $uploadfilename

Comment: @reinraus $uploadfilename = $_FILES[fileUploader][name]

Comment: Рекомендую почитать что-нибудь про юникод, юникодо- и escape-последовательности, чтобы понять откуда ноги растут.

Comment: Проверь кодировку файла , Если UT8 with Bom то поставь without Bom , возможная причина

Answer (score 1):

> `"\u0414\u4414"`

В этой строке нет слешей, это символы Юникод, обозначенные кодирующей последовательностью `\uxxxx`

> `"\\u0414\\u4414"`

А в этой есть, здесь слеши заэкранированы

```
echo $ret = substr_count("\\u0414\\u4414",'\\'); // 2
```

---

Если исходную строку вы видите в JSON, декодируйте его через json_decode:

```
echo $s = json_encode('Привет'); // "\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"
echo "\n";
echo json_decode($s); // Привет
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/#[^\s]+/', $input, $output);
```

только тут я выбираю все слова с #
подпили под себя